# Single cell with structured table references with Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to find the Excel 2007 syntax, for getting the cell (eg. 2nd row, 3rd column), in table reference flavor.

To be clear, ref to the [Microsoft - Using structured references with Excel tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx) page. It is clearly possible to refer a cell, eg.    =DeptSales[[#This Row], [ComAmt]]

but, what if I need just the 2nd row?   =TableName[2, [ColumnName]]
I've tryed any syntax but no one works ...please help me

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use structured table references where your `1` row AND `A` column are full of 'headers'. These references are designed to allow easy lookup of data on a 2-dimensional table:

```
=TableName[[#RowName],[ColumnName]]
```

If you need the 2nd row, 3rd column and you haven't structured your table in this way, you'll have to just use `C2`.

Comment: How to do you actually make a "RowName"? All Excel offers me are all, data, headers and totals.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this post](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/116365-reference-a-single-cell-in-a-table-using-structured-referencing):

> You could use something like
>
> ```
> =index(Table1[colA],1)
> ```
>
> for example. Or if the formula is on the row you want, just:
>
> ```
> =Table1[colA]
> ```

Answer (score -1):

I used a vlookup to avoid the problem...

I added in my table `tblContactPerson` the index (ID) of the source datable (`tblClientContact`) and use this `(tblContactPerson[@[id]:[id]])`.

```
=VLOOKUP(tblContactPerson[@[id]:[id]];tblClientContact;3;FALSE))
```

Then I added a test to avoid #NA

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(tblContactPerson[@[id]:[id]];tblClientContact;3;FALSE));"";VLOOKUP(tblContactPerson[@[id]:[id]];tblClientContact;3;FALSE))
```